# Getting Header Data with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm writing a web app for EVE online in sinatra,and want to retrive header data.

In php I can get data from a header variable with:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED']
```

how can I do the same in a sinatra page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

env['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED']